# trouble getting pending transaction receipt for Binance Smart Chain

Tags: python, web3py, binance-smart-chain

I can not get transaction receipt for BSC chain. I tried 3 different approaches but I failed.

Here is my code:

```
def get_transaction_recipt(txid):
    recipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txid)
    print(recipt)

async def get_event():
    async with connect('wss://bsc.getblock.io/mainnet/?api_key=<api-key>') as ws:
        await ws.send('{"id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newPendingTransactions"]}')
        subscription_response = await ws.recv()
        print(subscription_response)

        while True:
            try:
                message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=60)
                txid = (json.loads(message)['params']['result']) # 

                threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=[txid]).start()
                pass
            except:
                pass
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(get_event())
```

I can get new pending Transaction hashes but i get error calling get_transaction_recipt function

this is the error

```
web3.exceptions.TransactionNotFound: Transaction with hash: <TransactinHash> not found.
```

I also tried

```
web3_pending_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
while True:
   transaction_hashes = web3.eth.getFilterChanges(web3_pending_filter.filter_id)
```

but the result was empty list

I also tried this code:

```
list_of_block_transactions = web3.eth.getBlock('pending', full_transactions=True).transactions
for transaction in list_of_block_transactions:
   get(transaction)
```

and I got list of latest block transaction in list_of_block_transactions. NOT PENDINGS!!

but when trying with ETH blockchain the result was ok and returned me with all transaction receipts

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, seems like you try to get receipts for transactions that didn't take place yet. Block needs to be closed before they're available.

Comment: Answers should contains revision of the code posted in the questions. The right place for short line answers, that contains considerations rather than actual improvement, is the comment section

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).